# Retrieve data from Firebase into Listview

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data from Firebase but nothing pulls through. The app is written successfully however when it tries to get the info back it just shows a blank screen. My Firebase structure is `Saica>Calendar>key>Data`

I have included a picture of my Firebase Structure

[image]

This is my code:

```
public class Admin_ViewEvent extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView mListView;
private ArrayList<String> mMeetings = new ArrayList<>();
private Firebase mRef;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin__view_event);

    mRef = new Firebase("https://saica-sgb-77a4f.firebaseio.com/Meetings");
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mMeetings);
    mListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    mRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            mMeetings.add(value);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }
```

Comment: Which data you are trying to parse ?

Comment: @rahulkapoor The Date, Description as shown in the image

Comment: @rahulkapoor I've added the right picture for the meetings

Comment: @rahulkapoor how would i get the data into the Listview?

Comment: What does "nothing pulls through" mean? What versions? What errors are output to the console? Where is your onCancel method for the event listener? What is it outputting?

Answer (score 0):

As per your old Screenshot Reference you can get *date* and *description* from parent *Calendar* node. You can use below snippet to get details from *Meetings* node.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Calendar").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot childSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                String date = (String) childSnapShot.child("date").getValue();
                String desc = (String) childSnapShot.child("description").getValue();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the line

`mRef = new Firebase("https://saica-sgb-77a4f.firebaseio.com/Meetings");`

it looks like you are using the wrong firebase sdk. It's either an old version or the java server sdk, but definitely not a recent android sdk.

Check you `build.gradle`: you should have a line like this :

```
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.0"
```

To connect to your database and get a reference :

- Download the file `google-services.json` from the firebase console to your `app/` folder.
- Create the database reference like this :

  ```
  FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
  DatabaseReference mRef = db.getReference("Meetings") ;
  ```